# Select Drop-down list item in Word document with Powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-word, listbox

I'm working on a powershell script that opens Word documents as COM objects and edits them using content controls. Each content control is identified by the titles assigned to it in the Word document. I'm able to edit text boxes and check boxes, but I can't figure out how to change which item is selected in a dropdown list in the Word document.

Here's an example of the code I've tried that successfully changes the text box and check box, but isn't working for the dropdown list. All the documentation I've seen seems to be for VBA, so I don't know how to interact with the dropdown list using powershell. This was my best guess after poking around in the com object to see what properties the content controls have.

```
$filename = "C:\Path\File.docx"
$wordPg1 = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
$wordPg1.Visible = $False
$Page1Doc = $wordPg1.documents.open($filename)
$Page1Fields = $Page1Doc.ContentControls

           foreach($field in $Page1Fields)
           {
               switch ( $field.Title )
               {
                   # These two work
                   "Text Box"      { $field.Range.Text = "1234" }
                   "Check Box"     { $field.Checked = $TRUE }
                   # This one doesn't work
                   "Dropdown"      { $field.DropdownListEntries.Index = 2 }
               }
           }

$SaveAsFileName = "C:\Path\FileEdited.docx"
$Page1Doc.SaveAs([ref]$SaveAsFileName)

$Page1Doc.Close()
$wordPg1.Quit()
$null = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wordPg1)
```

This gives the error

Exception setting "Index": "The property 'Index' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct phraseology that I was looking for. This now works properly and selects the second item in the dropdown list.

```
$filename = "C:\Path\File.docx"
$wordPg1 = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
$wordPg1.Visible = $False
$Page1Doc = $wordPg1.documents.open($filename)
$Page1Fields = $Page1Doc.ContentControls

           foreach($field in $Page1Fields)
           {
               switch ( $field.Title )
               {
                   # These two work
                   "Text Box"      { $field.Range.Text = "1234" }
                   "Check Box"     { $field.Checked = $TRUE }
                   # This will now select the second item in the dropdown list
                   "Dropdown"      { $field.DropdownListEntries.Item(2).Select() }
               }
           }

$SaveAsFileName = "C:\Path\FileEdited.docx"
$Page1Doc.SaveAs([ref]$SaveAsFileName)

$Page1Doc.Close()
$wordPg1.Quit()
$null = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wordPg1)
```